# Replacing JSON.simple with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to replace JSON.simple with Jackson on the following code snippet:

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
request.put("String key", /String value/);
request.put("String key", /int value/);
...
```

It looks like that:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode request = mapper.createObjectNode();
((ObjectNode) request).put("String key", /String value/);
((ObjectNode) request).put("String key", /int value/);
```

I found a bit too complicated and ugly with the casting and extra declaration. Am I doing it wrong, any advice?

(I would like to send this JSON through REST entity)

Comment: In my project with jersey I just return the Object and Jackson will be used as the MessageBodyWriter when the request accepts json.  and everything is done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ObjectNode instead of JsonNode. Try this:

```
    ObjectNode request = mapper.createObjectNode();
    request.put("key", "val");
    System.out.println(request.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This link has pretty good information. I feel you should have objects instead of manually building your json.

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

```
public class Car {

    private String color;
    private String type;

    // standard getters setters
}
```

Then

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Car car = new Car("yellow", "renault");
String output = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(car);
```

Output:

```
{"color":"yellow","type":"renault"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like that

```
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ObjectNode request = mapper.createObjectNode();
            request.put("String key", /String value/);
            request.put("String key", /int value/);
```